# Is there a faster and recommended way to combine encrypted tar and encrypted symmetric key with which tar was encrypted?

Tags: bash, encryption, cryptography, sh, busybox

We are using a custom board based on Beaglebone black (AM335x). To upgrade the board’s firmware, we shall be using an encrypted firmware image.

As you would have already guessed, we will be using symmetric encryption to encrypt a large firmware file (fimware.tar) and then encrypt the symmetric key with an asymmetric key. So we have two files which to give to the user for upgrading his board.

We don’t want to do that; we want to give only one file to each user. So we have to somehow combine the encrypted firmware image and the encrypted symmetric key.

I thought of two strategies. The firmware is encrypted using a bash script.

1. Tar the encrypted firmware and the encrypted symmetric key.

   - Problem: This is very slow.
2. Append the encrypted symmetric key to the encrypted tar file.

   - Problem: This doesn’t feel like a clean approach, does it?

Are there any better (and faster) ways to handle this?

Comment: If you control the program that does the decryption (it sounds like you do), then (2) seems like a good solution (maybe the other way around if that makes it easier to retrieve the key).

Comment: @Thilo thank you for suggestion, me too inclined to use 2nd solution as it would reduce total encryption and decryption time, however I am willing to look for better solution if any.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this:

1. use a well known container format such as OpenPGP or CMS;
2. pick a less well known / standardized format that happens to confirm to your requirements;
3. define your own container format.

Option 1 should of course be preferred as this is likely the most secure option. It will also mean you can use standard libraries.

Option 2 requires you to perform research to see if that option fits your needs and is secure.

Option 3 would be a good option if code and format size optimization is a prime concern.

For option 3 you could e.g. use a version / format specifier (1 byte), then the wrapped key (prefixed with a length) and then the firmware (anything after the wrapped key).

Comment: Thank you for reply, I am thinking on similar lines. Your approval has strengthened my idea.